# Period " . " doesn't come into PHP variable in GET requests in URL Rewriting mode

Tags: php, variables, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

When I enter a value from browser URL bar, the value comes to a php variable via GET request and displays the value as expected, but the problem here is when I enter a value with a period  **.** at the end of the value, the value only is displaying but the period isn't displaying. How to fix this issue? I want it to be display the value with the period.
below is my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['value'])){ // value comes from the browser URL bar
$val = $_GET['value'];
echo $val;
}
```

**Question update**
I forgot to mention that I am using URL rewriting mode, and this happens when I get the value via URL rewritten mode. But when i get the value from original URL including the parameter name (index.php?value=) the dot displays as expected.

*Page name index.php*

```
if (isset($_GET['value'])){ // value comes from the browser URL bar
$val = $_GET['value'];
echo $val;
}
```

*my .htaccess file*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/([a-z0-9_/.]+)/?$ /review/index.php?value=$1 [L]
```

**Look at the first output: in that if i place the period at the end of a value, the value only displays. but in example two: if I include the period in the middle of the value, the value displays with the period. Why is this happening?**

*Outputs*

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show how you pass the url. Do you urlencode the parameters?

Comment: Please add an example of URL given, what's expected and what is received.

Comment: I am not passing the value by php, I am passing it directly from the browser URL bar

Comment: @AnthonyB okay. Hold on

Comment: I have tested your code and it works perfectly fine for me. I am passing url like

www.example.com/test.php?value=smit.

I am getting smit. as a response.

Comment: @SougataBose how I add url encode, when I enter the value **from only direct URL**? I am not passing the value. I am entering the value directly from the URL bar

Comment: @SmitRaval try sending the value (smit.) directly from the URL bar

Comment: I am sending it directly from the URL bar. :)

Comment: You'll get a `PHP Parse error` with that code, missing a `;` in `echo $val`

Comment: @SmitRaval you there? I forgot to mention a thing on the question

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code (except the missing `;`), works as expected. Are you doing any server rewrites that may be stripping the `.`?

Comment: Yes what did you forgot? @SaraRobert

Comment: What's the output of `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`?

Comment: sorry for the delay @SmitRaval

Comment: @AnthonyB can you get an idea from the updated question?

Comment: @SmitRaval yeah the dot displays as expected when entering the value directly from the url bar **with the original url** but it doesn't work with the url rewriting mode

Comment: @revo  that was a syntax error by me when I was trying the demo lol

Comment: @SaraRobert .htaccess rewrite mod is your issue.

Comment: @SaraRobert I guess your problem is in the rewriting instructions. Also, I think the slash `/` needs to be escaped, as `\/`. Otherwise, your regex [seems OK](https://regex101.com/r/1D9tNl/1).

Comment: I wanted you to echo that server variable and show us its output.

Comment: @AnthonyB how do i escape? can you show me a example?

Comment: @revo can we show outputs here?

Comment: @SaraRobert Please try `RewriteRule ^index/([a-z0-9_\/.]+)/?$ /review/index.php?value=$1 [L]` (The slash is preceded by a backslash).

Comment: By editing your question and putting the output line in it?!

Comment: @AnthonyB That doesn't work

Comment: @revo I have uploaded the output. look at them

Comment: and gimme a solution please

Comment: @AnthonyB actually the reason i have put **/** one 'cause to escape the **.** which means to say the regex to get only periods not all the syllables

Comment: @SmitRaval then how could i fix it? about I have included the outputs as well

Comment: Please do what I said previously: `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Comment: @revo okay. I have uploaded that one as well

Comment: @SaraRobert to escape the period '.' you'd use a backslash, not a slash. If you test your regex on a website like [101regex](https://regex101.com/) it will warn you about the slash '/'. Please try to remove the slash and either let the period as it or prefixe it with a backslash.  
`RewriteRule ^index/([a-z0-9_.]+)/?$ /review/index.php?value=$1 [L]`

Comment: @AnthonyB yeah that was a mistake.  but the thing is if i allow only periods by putting a back slash, or even just let the period as it is, the problem still happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this. Because I am not getting the period at the end of the values, I came up with a solution with PHP's SERVER variable. I am getting the current page full url by [$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and then exploding them and getting the query string. Below is the method of it.

```php
<?php
$getQueryString = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

echo getQueryString[3];
```

Below there is the output I am getting the period at the end of the values. See

[image: output image click here]

Comment: If your are looking for the last part of your array, you'd use `end($getQueryString)`, so even if you add a part before the end your code keeps working.

Comment: Also, that I've reproduced the whole example that is in your question on my local, with a domain, the .htaccess, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @AnthonyB What do you mean? Did you try the whole example which I added in my question and then it worked well for you? you mean when you enter a value with a period at the end of it, and you can see it with the period in you browser as the output?

Comment: I've created a domain 'sotest.local' on my MAMP instance, using PHP 7.2.2. I've created a file `index.php`, and used your `.htaccess` file. So the example is the same. I've tested with a parameter `truc.` with a period at the end, and the period was in the variable. I've seen it in my browser.

Comment: @AnthonyB Then do you know the reason why that isn't coming in my browser? I remember someone also said that this one worked perfectly for them as well

Comment: Perhaps about your PHP version? The next time please add this information to your question. The only difference seems to be the PHP version, but perhaps there is an other configuration option. It's hard to say.

Comment: How did you input the value in the URL bar? Did you input it through the original URL or Rewritten URL which means right after the **/** ?

Comment: @AnthonyB what do you mean by this "The next time please add this information to your question."?

Comment: My URL was the rewritten one, like `/review/index.php/truc.`

Comment: I mean when asking a question it's useful to give your PHP version, Apache version and why not OS.

Comment: @AnthonyB I asked the person who's output works fine as yours, what is their PHP version which they tested the problem, they said they tested that in PHP 7 as well as it works perfectly on in PHP 5.3 as well. So it is clear that the PHP version isn't the problem though.

Comment: So there is something else, but without more informations I can't say.